# Message Bubble UILabel for making an interactive app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uilabel

I want a UILabel like this. Where can I find one ?

[image: message bubble]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an imageview with the bubble image. add a uilabel as subview of the imageview and position it.

```
UIImageView *imgv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
imgv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble.png"];
```

//position the label to center of imageview

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,30,60,40)];
[imgv addSubview:lbl];
[lbl release];

[self.view addSubview:imgv];
[imgv release];
```